# Why Spark stage's Executor Computing Time takes much more time than usual when run as the first action?

Tags: apache-spark

Here's my code:

```
import time
import random

NUM_SAMPLES = 1000000
def sample(p):
  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
  return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

  count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

[image]

Here's the stages page, it takes about 0.5s much more time for the stage0 than the other stages and I want to know where the 0.5s gone? Additional info, the main different is in Executor Computing Time.

[image]

Comment: What is data localization for your tasks? Is the behavior same for every run ?

Comment: localhost, yes.